# how to update jsonb column using laravel query

Tags: laravel, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-json

I want to update the `available` to `false` where `toy->id=27`. Can any give me the laravel eloquent query for this? Thanks.

```
{
   "color":"red",
   "toy":{
      "id":27,
      "name":"Truck",
      "price":12,
      "available":true
   },
   "quantity":"12"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgresql you can use JSONB_SET like below:

```
update table set data=JSONB_SET(data, '{toy,available}','false') where data->'toy'->>'id'='27';
```

You can do this in **DB::update** i.e.

```php
DB.update("update table set data=JSONB_SET(data, '{toy,available}','false') where data->'toy'->>'id'='27';
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#database-transactions